# dyld not loading Ogre library

Tags: c++, macos, clion, ogre, dyld

I am trying to setup an environment to develop an Ogre3D application. I have manually compiled Ogre into folder `/opt/Ogre3D/ogre-1.11.5/build` and created a CMake project in CLion with this content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(sample)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(OGRE_DIR /opt/Ogre3D/ogre-1.11.5/build/sdk/cmake)

# specify which version and components you need
find_package(OGRE 1.11 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Bites RTShaderSystem)

# copy resource.cfg next to our binaries where OGRE looks for it
file(COPY ${OGRE_CONFIG_DIR}/resources.cfg DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

add_executable(sample main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sample ${OGRE_LIBRARIES})
```

when I try to run it, compilation is OK but then it can't execute it:

```sh
/Users/diego/CLionProjects/ogre/sample/cmake-build-debug/sample
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/OgreBites.framework/Versions/1.11.5/OgreBites
  Referenced from: /Users/diego/CLionProjects/ogre/sample/cmake-build-debug/sample
  Reason: image not found

Process finished with exit code 6
```

I have looked at `otool -l /opt/Ogre3D/ogre-1.11.5/build/lib/macosx/OgreBites.framework/Versions/1.11.5/OgreBites` and there is a command `LC_ID_DYLIB` with the name `@executable_path/../Frameworks/OgreBites.framework/Versions/1.11.5/OgreBites`, which matches the path given in the runtime error. However I don't know which step to take now as I have few experience with native library resolution on macOS.

**Update:**

Executing the command `install_name_tool` makes the linker find the library, but then it fails with the next one. I suppose/hope there is an option in CMake to pass it to the compiler so the binary files created during Ogre's compilation do not use the `@execute_path` directive?

Comment: Can you resolve the @executable_path/../Frameworks and check if the dylib is in there?

Comment: @executable_path resolves as the folder in which the compiled program is executed, which in my case is `/Users/diego/CLionProjects/ogre/sample/cmake-build-debug`. The library however is located in `/opt/Ogre3D/ogre-1.11.5/build/lib/macosx/OgreBites.framework/Versions/1.11.5` which is a different folder. Using `install_name_tool -change @executable_path/../Frameworks/OgreBites.framework/Versions/1.11.5/OgreBites /opt/Ogre3D/ogre-1.11.5/build/lib/macosx/OgreBites.framework/Versions/1.11.5/OgreBites sample` fixes the problem but then it fails with the next library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced with the same problem, when using clion to build ogre in macos.

**I found the symbolic links were invalid in the directory cmake-build-debug/bin/SampleBrowser.app/Contents/Frameworks**.

I guess these symbolic links should point to
these frameworks int the cmake-build-debug/lib/macosx. So I modified the file where executed `ln` to create these symbolic links.

In the file Samples/Browser/CMakeLists.txt, change

```
set(OGRE_OSX_BUILD_CONFIGURATION "${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/$(CONFIGURATION)")
```

into

```
set(OGRE_OSX_BUILD_CONFIGURATION "macosx")
```

And clean and rebuild, then the problem will disappear.